# Replacing values in column with values in lookup table of column names conditionally

Tags: r

I am working with two tables:

```
t1<-data.frame(Name=c("Waldo","Mark","Harold","Earl"),Number=c(1,4,3,9))
```

and

```
t2<-data.frame(Whatever=c("does","not","really","matter","at","all"),Waldo=c(0,1,1,0,0,1),Mark=c(1,0,1,1,0,0),Harold=c(0,1,0,0,0,0),Earl=c(1,1,1,1,0,0),Extra=c("another","column","appearing","in","this","table"))
```

What I would like to do is replace the 1's in `t2` with the lookup values from `t1`.  The column names for `t2` appear as records in `t1`. All 0 values in `t2` should stay intact.

In my true data, there are hundreds of columns in `t2`, and hundreds of rows in `t1`.

There are also several columns in `t2` that should not be impacted by this coding, but should remain in the final output.

Is there a best practice for coding this?

Desired output for the example is below:

```
Whatever   Waldo  Mark  Harold  Earl  Extra
does       0      4     0       9     another
not        1      0     3       9     column
really     1      4     0       9     appearing
matter     0      4     0       9     in
at         0      0     0       0     this
all        1      0     0       0     table
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be flexible enough for your actual dataset:

```
my_function <- function(df, lookup) {
  for(i in names(df)) {
    df[[as.character(i)]][df[[as.character(i)]] == 1] <- lookup$Number[lookup$Name == as.character(i)]
  }
  return(df)
}

my_function(t2, t1)
#   Whatever Waldo Mark Harold Earl     Extra
# 1     does     0    4      0    9   another
# 2      not     1    0      3    9    column
# 3   really     1    4      0    9 appearing
# 4   matter     0    4      0    9        in
# 5       at     0    0      0    0      this
# 6      all     1    0      0    0     table
```

Comment: This looks great! Very few, efficient lines of code. I am running in to an error "replacement has length zero" when applying to my data, though.  (although your code runs perfectly with the example data!) Any thoughts as to why? Columns take a t1$`Smith,John` format. Could this perhaps be the issue?

Comment: There should be a mismatch between your dataset and lookup table. Make sure that all the columns in actual dataset have correspondence in the lookup table. Every column name should appear in the lookup table as is.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a `tidyverse` workflow that may be a little excessive for this example, but should scale well for larger datasets. I'll break it into steps so it isn't too convoluted going from wide-shaped data to long to wide again:

First I reshape `t2` into a long format and filter for observations with 1:

```r
library(tidyverse)

t2 %>%
  gather(key = Name, value = value, -Whatever, -Extra) %>%
  filter(value == 1)
#>    Whatever     Extra   Name value
#> 1       not    column  Waldo     1
#> 2    really appearing  Waldo     1
#> 3       all     table  Waldo     1
#> 4      does   another   Mark     1
#> 5    really appearing   Mark     1
#> 6    matter        in   Mark     1
#> 7       not    column Harold     1
#> 8      does   another   Earl     1
#> 9       not    column   Earl     1
#> 10   really appearing   Earl     1
#> 11   matter        in   Earl     1
```

Then I join that with `t1`, using `left_join` in case there are any observations in `t2` that don't have matches in `t1`. That gets me the `Number` column from `t1`, so now I can drop the `value` column from gathering:

```r
t2 %>%
  gather(key = Name, value = value, -Whatever, -Extra) %>%
  filter(value == 1) %>%
  left_join(t1, by = "Name") %>%
  select(-value)
#>    Whatever     Extra   Name Number
#> 1       not    column  Waldo      1
#> 2    really appearing  Waldo      1
#> 3       all     table  Waldo      1
#> 4      does   another   Mark      4
#> 5    really appearing   Mark      4
#> 6    matter        in   Mark      4
#> 7       not    column Harold      3
#> 8      does   another   Earl      9
#> 9       not    column   Earl      9
#> 10   really appearing   Earl      9
#> 11   matter        in   Earl      9
```

Then I use `spread` to bring it back to a wide format. Note that these functions create factors to order them, so at the end the spread columns are in alphabetical order. You can use `select` to change the order of columns if you need to.

The start to finish process:

```r
t2 %>%
  gather(key = Name, value = value, -Whatever, -Extra) %>%
  filter(value == 1) %>%
  left_join(t1, by = "Name") %>%
  select(-value) %>%
  spread(key = Name, value = Number, fill = 0)
#>   Whatever     Extra Earl Harold Mark Waldo
#> 1      all     table    0      0    0     1
#> 2     does   another    9      0    4     0
#> 3   matter        in    9      0    4     0
#> 4      not    column    9      3    0     1
#> 5   really appearing    9      0    4     1
```

Created on 2018-08-14 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Comment: I like the tidyverse style! Very tidy. How might you modify this if there were, say hundreds of columns similar to `Whatever` and `Extra`?

Comment: All you would need to do is mark those as excluded in `gather`. So replacing `-Whatever, -Extra` with `-Whatever, -Extra, -Extra2, -Extra3`... Or you could use `tidyselect` helpers, like `starts_with` if there's some labelling scheme for them, or `-Whatever:-Extra99` to exclude all columns between `Whatever` and `Extra99` should also work